# Referencing the Objects of 2D array into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I need to create an ArrayList from a 2D Array where the ArrayList works as a linear "view" of the array. The thing thats bothering me is that when I change the value of some element of the original Array, it doesnt change in the List. While debugging, I observed that the reference to the object in the array changes, but it stays the same in the list. This is how I initialize the List:

```java
public class ColeccionArray2D<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> data = new ArrayList<E>();
    private int size = 0;

    public ColeccionArray2D(E[][] contenido) {
        data = twoDArrayToList(contenido);
        this.size = data.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<E> twoDArrayToList(E[][] twoDArray) {
        int index = 0;
        ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
                list.add(index, twoDArray[i][j]);
                index++;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But if I change the original array:

```java
arrayInteger[0][0] = -1;
```

The reference on the array changes, but it stays the same in the list, as in the Integer object doesn't change.
My best guess is that I need to "update" the view as operations happen, but it defeats the purpose of referencing the elements of the original array.
Is there a way to add *the reference* of the index (for example [0][0]) to the list? So when the object inside changes, it changes as well in the list?

Comment: An `ArrayList` won't work for what you want because the `ArrayList` is basically a **copy** of your 2D array, not a "view" of it.   You need a custom `List` implementation which acts like a view, referring `get` and `set` operations on itself to appropriate operations on the underlying 2D array.

Comment: You can do what @KevinAnderson suggests easily by using [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)... Even if you calculate the position on the fly (for a get) it's possibly not as bad you think because you don't have extra memory allocations / copies going on (or if you know the 2D array was large you could precalculate the indexes of all the starts of rows...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create an ArrayList from a 2D Array where the ArrayList works as a linear "view" of the array.

The code presented in the question indeed does not implement a view of the array.  Instead, it just copies the contents of the array (shallowly) at one point in time, and is subsequently independent.

It is possible to create a custom `List` implementation that uses your 2D array as the backing element store.  This could be implemented such that the `List.set()` method replaces the corresponding reference in the backing store with the one specified as an argument.  This would be facilitated by extending [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html) and overriding (only) `get()`, `set()`, and `size()`.

But other than by doing similar with `ArrayList` as a base class, you cannot accomplish your aim with specifically an `ArrayList`.  And using `ArrayList` as a base would be problematic, because some of the things one can do with an `ArrayList`, such as lengthening it with `add()` or shrinking it with `remove()`, do not make sense for a view of a fixed-size object such as an array.

Comment: I do not necessarily need to use an ArrayList, just implement a version of `AbstractCollection` to act as a view over the array. Could you please elaborate on how to use said Array as the backing store?

Comment: @DanielMerueloMonzón, there's not much more to say.  The custom `List` keeps a reference to the array, which presumably would initially be provided as a constructor argument.  It implements `get()` as retrieving the appropriate array element and returning it.  It implements `set()` by storing the argument in the appropriate array element.  It implements `size()` in terms of the number of elements in the array.